# Finding nearest date rates in SQL

Tags: sql, datastage

Input :1

```
SKU  date
1    2/1/18
2    4/2/18
```

input: 2

```
date     rate
1/1/18   10
31/1/18  20
5/2/18   40
3/1/18   30
```

output :

```
SKU  DATE   RATE

1    2/1/18  10
2    4/2/18  20
```

Note : How output will come is if the date of input1 >=input2 then it will take input2 rate,input 2 is nearest less than to input 1.

I tried but strucked somewhere.
So please help me out this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are pretty vendor specific. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
    a.SKU,
    a.Date,
    (select TOP 1 rate from Table_2 where Date < a.Date order by Date desc) as Rate
from table_1 a
```